# Click or Touch End or Mouse Down on Android 5 and above using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, slider

I have this code on this URL:
http://emadzedan.com/otlehmobile/changeFlight.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Fliter Interaction
    var xpos = 0;
    var ypos = 0;
    var oldX = 0;
    var oldY = 0;
    var newX = 0;
    var newY = 0;
    $(".headerOfFilter, .filtercontentcell").bind('touchstart mousedown', function(e){
        xpos = e.offsetX === undefined ? e.originalEvent.layerX : e.offsetX;
        ypos = e.offsetY === undefined ? e.originalEvent.layerY : e.offsetY;
        oldX = xpos;
        oldY = ypos;
    });
    $(".headerOfFilter, .filtercontentcell").bind('touchend mouseup', function(e){
        xpos = e.offsetX === undefined ? e.originalEvent.layerX : e.offsetX;
        ypos = e.offsetY === undefined ? e.originalEvent.layerY : e.offsetY;
        newX = xpos;
        newY = ypos;
        alert("insideUpNew15 " + oldX + "," + oldY + " " + newX + "," + newY);
        if((oldX <= newX+20) && (oldX >= newX-20) && (oldY <= newY+20) && (oldY >= newY-20)){
            //alert("insideNew15");
            $(".headerOfFilter, .filtercontentcell").removeClass("blueBGWithWhiteText");
            $(this).addClass("blueBGWithWhiteText");
            alert("ddd3");
        }
    });
});
```

the problem is that no event is firing on android while iphone and windows is working.

the main problem is that the clicking buttons is on slider which moves so click is not accurate on slider so I made the above code to create a big area for mouse down or touch end. it used to work on android 4 and below but I upgrade my phone to android 5 and my developer upgraded to android 6 and we both can not fire the click event on the slider (I'm a web designer and front end developer)

by the way the slider I'm using is called smoothTouchScroll
http://smoothtouchscroll.com/

any body can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just if someone else faced the same my code is working but need to remove the if statement in the mouseup event that is all.